# Is it necessary to test a TDD-based API in 3rd party app like Postman?

Tags: testing

I just finished my TDD-based REST API. And I would like to use Postman to document it for the frontend team until I realized it has its own test script. Now I'm wondering, is it necessary to double test it?

Comment: Why not talk to the frontend team about it? Do they know how to interpret those tests? Are they at a useful level of abstraction and granularity? Are they written in a language they're familiar with, even? Maybe you don't need to re-test it with Postman, but that doesn't mean that the existing tests also achieve the goal of communicating the API to its consumers.

Comment: i see.. learnt something new about it, i'll ask the frontend team. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's nothing special about third party testing tools.

I would aim for the following in your tests

- Automation. However you test the test have to run and report automatically. Without manual intervention.
- Tests run the same way that its used. So if you have a client, test the api through the client, If you send out postman collections test with the postman collections
- Keep test code small. Don't write a whole client and models just for your tests. Don't write complicated infrastructure to automate a third party tool